# Create 2 new conditional columns with dependence postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to create two new columns from a query in postgresql, one depending on existing data, and the other depnding on the new column, i.e

```
existing_col   new_col   new_col2
a              1         2
b              0         0
```

I have tried:

```
select existing_col, 
case when existing_col like 'a' then 1 else 0 end  as new_col  
case when new_col like 1 then 2 else 0 end as new_col2
from table
```

however this is giving me the error that new_col doesn't exist, how can I achieve this?

Comment: you are missing `end` after case

Comment: Have corrected that error still doesn't work.

Comment: You can't reference `new_col` on the same level where you introduce the alias

Comment: Is there any way to achieve what I want without altering the original table?

Comment: `case when new_col` will need a subquery

Comment: @VaoTsun are you able to elaborate?

Comment: @user124123 try qry in answer?

Comment: That is giving me syntax error at or near "from"

Comment: I created table and fixed `1 ~ 1` comparison in my answer. rest is like yours - It returns result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated:**

(I modified your qry a little no avoid like operator for integers)

```
t=# create table "table" (existing_col text);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 50.189 ms
t=# insert into "table" values('a'),('b');
INSERT 0 2
Time: 0.911 ms
t=# select *,case when new_col like 1 then 2 else 0 end as new_col2
t-#     from (
t(#       select existing_col,
t(#       case when existing_col like 'a' then 1 else 0 end as new_col
t(#     from "table") al
t-# ;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~ integer
LINE 1: select *,case when new_col like 1 then 2 else 0 end as new_c...
                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Time: 0.514 ms
t=#     select *,case when new_col = 1 then 2 else 0 end as new_col2
t-#     from (
t(#       select existing_col,
t(#       case when existing_col like 'a' then 1 else 0 end as new_col
t(#     from "table") al
t-# ;
 existing_col | new_col | new_col2
--------------+---------+----------
 a            |       1 |        2
 b            |       0 |        0
(2 rows)

Time: 0.347 ms
```

[as in docs:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html)

> ```
> CASE WHEN condition THEN result
>      [WHEN ...]
>      [ELSE result]
> END
> ```